# Breathing in magic fog?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, breathing

I know the rules do not say anything on this. And a Fog Cloud is probably normal fog and breathable. But Solid Fog or Acid Fog seem like they would be hazardous to your health if breathed in. I know these spells usually last about a minute (1 round/level) so it won't be a terrible problem to hold one's breath. I'm just curious on how to fluff it, how to describe the situation, without going too deep into penalties the rules do not "allow". (I imagine Solid Fog as some sort of non-Neutonian fluid, inhibiting motion without extra pressure if standing still)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Acid Fog](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/acidFog.htm) is very much hazardous to your health, whether you deliberately breathe it on otherwise. In fact it deals 2D6 points of acid damage each round with no possible saves!

> ... this spell’s vapors are highly acidic ...  the fog deals 2d6
>   points of acid damage to each creature and object within it

For [Solid Fog](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/solidFog.htm) however there is no damage dealt as per the rules. The spell is a modified version of [Fog Cloud](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fogCloud.htm) which could just be a magical source of fairly mundane, albeit thick, fog. It's the movement-limiting thickness that seems to be poorly explained and causes problems.

There are three main reasons you could use for its motion inhibiting properties:

1. Magic - The air is literally thick with vapour and you could suggest that it is like their characters are being forced to fight whilst wading through water.
2. Vision - The slowness of movement could also be described as being partially caused by the lack of visibility. Everyone is moving around a lot more slowly and carefully because they can't see where they are going! The Movement rules do suggest that poor visibility would [hamper movement speed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/exploration-movement#TOC-Table:-Hampered-Movement).
3. Humidity and Density - Lastly, you could also describe a shortness of breath, which could partially account for the various penalties the spell causes.

If the fog has a mixture of all these effects then you are not simply reliant on its inherent 'thickness' to slow people down. This also makes it easier to explain how characters can still breathe while in its area of effect.

As long as the oxygen content of the air is sufficient then it shouldn't stop the characters from breathing enough not to die, although describing difficulties in doing so could certainly be a way of ramping up the tension!